# making the nav bar stacked span width as per the text width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created stacked nav bar in bootstrap. I have problem with aligning width as per the text in it. ie when I hover on " about us " tab it has to show the  background color as per the size of the text.

Image reference

[image: Refer the Image]

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav  nav-stacked ">
    <li><a href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#project">PROJECT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#current-project">CURRENT PROJECT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#e-brochure">E-BROCHURE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is the background on the `li` tag or on the `a` tag?

Comment: its on a tag Thq but Vignesh solved problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` in `a` tag so that width sets as per text width.